# How can i find every occurance of shortcode tag with regex?

Tags: regex

I'm using the following regex to find every occurrence of shortcode:

```
\[div([^\]]*)\]([^\£]*)\[\/div\]
```

Test string:

```
[div w="6"]<div>test text</div>[/div][div w="3"]2[/div][div w="3"]3[/div]
```

But i am only able to find longest path.

Basically i want to extract the every occurrence of shortcode tag from the content.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eU3mK9/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a non-greedy regex.

```
\[div([^\]]*)\](.*?)\[\/div\]
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eU3mK9/2)

Answer (score 1):

```
\[div[^\]]*\]([^\£]*?)\[\/div\]

                    ^^
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eU3mK9/4